# Purchased Theme to Custom Made Theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I bought a theme from Themeforest and now I would like to convert it to a custom made theme. I was creating the theme with the Underscores theme: http://underscores.me/ but how do I keep the same custom post types in the next theme?

Is this less time consuming than recoding the purchased theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the Theme itself, some company sells very good themes with clear code like Elegantthemes of themeforest some not.

I personnally recoded a theme from ElegantThemes and it was not so long.

In fact if you just want to keep your custom post types i think i'll be faster to recode a part of the purchased theme.