# How to create a plone theme from a existing theme

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

This question looks a lot similar to [Purchased Theme to Custom Made Theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460490/purchased-theme-to-custom-made-theme) .

I purchased a theme which uses Twitter Bootstrap, using which I built a basic website. I stumbled upon Plone (4.3) after my website went beta. I understand that you can make plone the backend for the existing design by creating a theme and using that theme file in the "Theming" option of "Site Setup". I am really not sure how to create this theme file with my existing theme. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plone 4.3 ships with a sample bootstrap-based theme. I'd start by:

1. Turning on plone.app.theming (in the add/remove configlet),
2. Go to the theming config panel
3. Clone the bootstrap sample;
4. Start updating it with items from your bootstrap theme.

Read the [plone.app.theming manual](http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.theming/userguide.html) for vital information on how it all works.